# How to get xcode simulator working after moving Library/Developer to an external harddrive

Tags: xcode, symlink

How do I get device simulator working in xcode after moving the Library/Developer file to an external hard drive and symlinking it. Yes, I've already symlinked the files from Developer.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) What is the version of Xcode that you are using?

Comment: Don't worry about it. It's not possible. You have to have Library/Developer on your internal ssd for simulator to work. It's possible individual folders except the ones that have the simulators in it can be symlinked but not the root Developer files as a whole. Xcode version is irrelevant for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about it. It's not possible. You have to have Library/Developer on your internal ssd for simulator to work. It's possible individual folders except the ones that have the simulators in it can be symlinked but not the root Developer files as a whole. Xcode version is irrelevant for this question.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is 100% correct. My home directory is on an *external* SSD and simulators work fine. I came across this question cause I was thinking of moving ~/Library/Developer to my internal fusion drive, where there's more space, and symlinking it. But I'll take your hint and leave well enough alone. It may be that files in ~/Library need to stay right there (whether or not it's internal). I've had trouble in the past trying to symlink certain folders where Quicktime player keeps its temporary files when recording.